# js object using a var with php in joomla module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla-extensions

I am creating a Joomla module that shows a progressbar from the ProgressBar.js plugin. As it is a module it needs to be setup so that it can load multiple objects on one page and therefore I can't hardcode the ID of the objects. So I use PHP to create the HTML objects with each there own ID.

```
<div id="progress<?php echo $module->id ?>"></div>
```

In this case it shows `id="progress198"`
When I use this together with this it works perfectly:

```
<script>
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

var pID = "<?php echo 'progress' . $module->id ?>";
//alert(pID);
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(progress198, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});
bar.animate(0.8);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

As you can see here `var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(progress198, {` this `198` is now hardcoded into it. Which is not the way it needs to be.

When I try this: `var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(pID, {` then nothing happens and when looking into the inspector it shows up exactly like that.

But when I decomment `alert(pID);` then it shows a alert with `progress198`.

So I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what I do wrong. Thanks in advance for helping.

#### To clarify the question

How should I put `pID` inside `var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(INHERE, {` on the place of `INHERE`.

Comment: This `new ProgressBar.Circle(progress198, {` only works because your browser lets you access elements directly via their id. Check the documentation: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming at I read the docs before asking the question and just gone over that page again but can't find what you are saying. Maybe you can do something with my clarification because I don't think it really is a ProgressBar problem but rather a Javascript problem. I am writing the code wrong. I do it right to output the alert but doing it wrong inside the object. If I only knew how to do it right :-) in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape/) the first parameter in `new ProgressBar.Circle(container[, options])` has to be a DOM element or a CSS selector.

Your browser seems to allow you to access elements by their `id`, otherwise

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(progress198, {
```

would throw a `ReferenceError: progress198 is not defined`

To fix your script you have two options:

1) Get the element first with `document.getElementById()`

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(document.getElementById(pID), {
```

2) make `pID` a valid id selector adding a `#`

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle("#" + pID, {
```

Comment: Thank you very much I used option 2 and works like a charm!